# Tcl-regexp of unbalanced brackets

Tags: tcl

every time I write:

```
set a "cell (number 3)"
regexp "cell (" $a
```

I get an error message that parentheses () not balanced.
how can I fix it?
I don't want to write `regexp "cell (number 3)" $a`

Answer (score 1):

The `(` character is special in regular expressions: it starts a pair of capturing parentheses.

You want to tell regexp that you want a *literal* open parenthesis:

```
regexp {cell \(} $a
# or
regexp {cell [(]} $a
```

It's best practice to enclose regular expression literals in braces not quotes: it allows you to minimize excessive backslashes to protect regex characters from the special *Tcl* meaning of them.